# Changes to keyboard layout resetted on restart

Tags: keyboard, startup, keyboard-layout, xkb

I edited `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` to customize the french-dvorak layout. I then selected french-dvorak layout (instead of french).

Now when I restart Ubuntu, I end up with the non-edited french-dvorak (my changes are ignored).

But if I switch to french, then back to french-dvorak, my changes are now taken into account...

How can I have my custom french-dvorak on startup? Is there some sort of cached version of the keyboard layout?

I don't understand how it can switch me to the official french-dvorak because I changed it, so it should no longer exist.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Ubuntu stores cached copies of the keyboard layouts in `/var/lib/xkb`.

To solve this issue, delete the xkm files in /var/lib/xkb: `sudo rm /var/lib/xkb/*.xkm` and logout and in again.

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

I found that in [this tutorial](http://ubuntu-help.blogspot.it/2013/10/solved-add-custom-characters-to.html) and it seems to work for me...